# Play Framework 2.2 action composition returning a custom object

Tags: scala, playframework, action, before-filter, playframework-2.2

I am trying to create a custom `play.api.mvc.Action` which can be used to populate a `CustomerAccount` based on the request and pass the `CustomerAccount` into the controller.

Following the [documentation for Play 2.2.x](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition) I've created an `Action` and `ActionBuilder` but I cannot seem to return the `CustomerAccount` from within the action.

My current code is:

```
case class AccountWrappedRequest[A](account: CustomerAccount, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

case class Account[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] {
  lazy val parser = action.parser

  def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    AccountService.getBySubdomain(request.host).map { account => 
      // Do something to return the account like return a new AccountWrappedRequest?
      action(AccountWrappedRequest(account, request))
    } getOrElse {
      Future.successful(NotFound(views.html.account_not_found()))
    }
  }
}

object AccountAction extends ActionBuilder[AccountWrappedRequest] { 
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AccountWrappedRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
    // Or here to pass it to the next request?
    block(request) // block(AccountWrappedRequest(account??, request))
  }

  override def composeAction[A](action: Action[A]) = Account(action) 
}
```

*Note: This will not compile because the `block(request)` function is expecting a type of `AccountWrappedRequest` which I cannot populate. It will compile when using a straight `Request`*

### Additionally...

Ultimately I want to be able to combine this Account action with an Authentication action so that the `CustomerAccount` can be passed into the Authentication action and user authentication can be provided based on that customer's account. I would then want to pass the customer account and user into the controller.

For example:

`Account(Authenticated(Action))) { request => request.account; request.user ... }` or better yet as individual objects not requiring a custom request object.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem, and so far find the following highly relevant: http://www.mariussoutier.com/blog/2013/09/17/playframework-2-2-action-building-action-composition/

Comment: @AndrewE thanks for that, I have seen that page before and it does have some useful information. I think I've come up with a solution which I've posted as an answer below. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but I have managed to come up with a solution that seems to work pretty well.

The key was to match on the request converting it into an `AccountWrappedRequest` inside `invokeBlock` before passing it on to the next request. If another Action in the chain is expecting a value from an earlier action in the chain you can then similarly match the request converting it into the type you need to access the request parameters.

Updating the example from the original question:

```
case class AccountWrappedRequest[A](account: CustomerAccount, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

case class Account[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] {
  lazy val parser = action.parser

  def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    AccountService.getBySubdomain(request.host).map { account => 
      action(AccountWrappedRequest(account, request))
    } getOrElse {
      Future.successful(NotFound(views.html.account_not_found()))
    }
  }
}

object AccountAction extends ActionBuilder[AccountWrappedRequest] { 
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AccountWrappedRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
    request match {
      case req: AccountRequest[A] => block(req)
      case _ => Future.successful(BadRequest("400 Invalid Request"))
    }
  }

  override def composeAction[A](action: Action[A]) = Account(action) 
}
```

Then inside the `apply()` method of another Action (the Authenticated action in my case) you can similarly do:

```
def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[SimpleResult] = {
  request match {
    case req: AccountRequest[A] => {
      // Do something that requires req.account
      val user = User(1, "New User")
      action(AuthenticatedWrappedRequest(req.account, user, request))
    }
    case _ => Future.successful(BadRequest("400 Invalid Request"))
  }
}
```

And you can chain the actions together in the ActionBuilder

```
override def composeAction[A](action: Action[A]) = Account(Authenticated(action))
```

If `AuthenticatedWrappedRequest` is then passed into the controller you would have access to `request.account`, `request.user` and all the usual request parameters.

As you can see there are a couple of cases where the response is unknown which would generate a `BadRequest`. In reality these should never get called as far as I can tell but they are in there just incase.

I would love to have some feedback on this solution as I'm still fairly new to Scala and I'm not sure if there might be a better way to do it with the same result but I hope this is of use to someone too.

Comment: Hello @David i am also facing similar problem, if possible look at my example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873343/play-framework-2-3-x-wrap-request-object-using-scala-oauth-in-play-framework

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a standalone small (ish) example that does what you're looking for:

https://github.com/aellerton/play-login-example

I gave up trying to use the `Security` classes that exist in the play framework proper. I'm sure they're good, but I just couldn't understand them.

Brief guide...

In the example code, a controller is declared as using the `AuthenticatedRequests` trait:

```
object UserSpecificController extends Controller with AuthenticatedRequests {
  ...
}
```

Forcing any page to require authentication (or redirect to get it) is done with the `RequireAuthentication` action:

```
def authenticatedIndex = RequireAuthentication { implicit request: AuthenticatedRequest[AnyContent] =>
  Ok("This content will be accessible only after logging in)
}
```

Signing out is done by using the `AbandonAuthentication` action:

```
def signOut = AbandonAuthentication { implicit request =>
  Ok("You're logged out.").withNewSession
}
```

Note that for this to work, you must override methods from the `AuthenticatedRequests` trait, e.g.:

```
override def authenticationRequired[A](request: Request[A]): Future[SimpleResult] = {
  Future.successful(
    Redirect(routes.LoginController.showLoginForm).withSession("goto" -> request.path)
  )
}
```

There's more to it; best to see the code.

HTH
Andrew